# Run 1 command to install 3 scripts from inside a script

Tags: bash, installation

I'm using a media server and each time when I want to reinstall my items, I have to first do script example

```
get file
make folder
cmod files
./install
```

then next file the same, and so on.

Is there a way I can add all the commands in one php file so if I run something like:

install 3 files, it just runs and cmods for me?

Comment: Is this php scripting or bash? Where is your broken piece of code?

Comment: Commands that you have provided are not valid bash commands. It is possible however to write a bash script that does the things you want to do as a one command.